# PHP curl timeout error detection

Tags: php, curl, error-handling, timeout

I use curl to perform a HTTP request like this:

```
$ch = curl_init();
$timeout = 5;
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,$timeout);

$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

How can I check if an error occurred, and whether it was a timeout error?

Comment: Curl or Divergence?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Use [`curl_errno()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-errno.php)

[Code 28](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) is timeout.

Comment: Which is named "CURLE_OPERATION_TIMEOUTED".

Comment: TIMEOUTED‽ Seriously, WTF is wrong with these people? Just to be clear, php.net's documentation (correctly) lists this unfortunate constant name. curl.haxx.se has better grammar but sadly php-curl will not recognize CURLE_OPERATION_TIMEDOUT.

Comment: @Lambart apparently CURLE_OPERATION_TIMEOUTED  was the original constant name used by curl, which they then changed to CURLE_OPERATION_TIMEDOUT while keeping the former as a now-undocumented alias. The latest version of PHP supports both; see the comment at http://php.net/manual/en/curl.constants.php#117928 for some history.

Comment: @MarkAmery glad they finally got that fixed up.

Answer (score 3):

you can check error number and its' description like this:

```
// Check if any error occurred
if(curl_errno($ch))
{
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
}
```

Comment: if you use curl as an Object, it would be much nicer.